# Is it possible to extend AppiumFieldDecorator class to make it accept custom annotations?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

Is it possible to extend `AppiumFieldDecorator` and make the `CustomAppiumFieldDecorator` class some how accept custom annotations?

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "selectButton")
@MyCustomAnnotation(val = "CustomValue")
MobileElement someElement;
```

Is that possible?

Link to the [class here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory/AppiumFieldDecorator.java)

```
public void click (MobileElement element) {
   element.click();
   element.log(); //This may be a custom method which will print the value in `MyCustomAnnotation` above
}
```

Comment: Sure is. Need more info here

Comment: @arias_JC : Added more info